# DOCTYPE not allowed Android Studio 3.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Upgrading to Android Studio 3.0.0, syncing and updating gradle plugin, I get the following error:

```
Error:DOCTYPE not allowed if function "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" is set to true.
```

What does this mean? Any suggestion to solve this? I need the IDE...

Comment: You need to add the layout, that's what this is connected to

Comment: Found any solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may see more specific details in the "Gradle Build" tab of Messages.

Remove the `<!DOCTYPE>` xml tag you have in any AndroidManifest or XML files.