# Android repository sdk update site not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to update sdk build tools to 27.0.3 but i dont get any updates at sdk manager.

[image: 27.0.3 is not in list]

Besides "Android Repository" in "SDK Update Sites" tab is disabled with the below error :

```
DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow_doctype_decl" set to true.
```

A screenshot :

[image: The Error]

What is the problem? How can i update SDK stuffs?
Using Android Studio 3.0.1 btw.

Comment: Refer to this Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940775/doctype-not-allowed-android-studio-3-0-0

Comment: @gorp88 I am not in a project. where should I check for that tag?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just toggled my proxy and set it to "Auto-detect proxy settings".

btw you can find proxy setting at "File >> Settings >> Appearance & Behavior >> System Settings >> HTTP Proxy".

That just fixed everything.

Comment: For latest Android Studio version "Giraffe" the settings are in "Welcome to Android Studio" Window >> Projects >> More Actions >> SDK Manager >>  Appearance & Behavior >> System Settings >> HTTP Proxy
You don't need to set a config url

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me by changing the time zone, calender format, and region to United States in Windows settings.

Comment: The "[Freedom of developers](https://github.com/freedomofdevelopers/fod)" project might also help in such situations.