# Cannot update repository in sdk update sites

Tags: android, sdk

I want to add recyclerview by adding this line to my project:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

but it can't do that and i got "cannot resolve recyclerview" error.
I find some solutions on google that sdk must be updated. In setting-> android SDK ->SDK update sites an error accrued:
[image]

I enabled auto-detect proxy setting in HTTP PROXY . but the errors exist.
what can i do?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update

Comment: thank u, i check the link but when i use 'Help-> check for updates' i got the error "Connection failed"

Comment: For above problem set the option to `"No Proxy"` from `"Auto-detect proxy settings"`.

Comment: Let me inform please.

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69614656/9918462.
You might find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

At first read [**`Update the IDE and SDK Tools`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update).

> Got the error "Connection failed"

You should change **`HTTP proxy settings`**.

[image]

1. From the menu bar, click **File > Settings** (on a Mac, click Android
   Studio > Preferences).
2. In the left pane, click **Appearance & Behavior > System Settings >
   HTTP Proxy**. The HTTP Proxy page appears.
3. Select **No proxy** settings.

Then **`Restart IDE`** and Upgrade.

Comment: I change the HTTP Proxy to No proxy and restart the IDE but still, I got the "Connection failed" error

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer Kindly check any system(or Anti virus) firewall on or off.